# Using Wifi when App is not active

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I have the following Problem:

I use a System.Threading.Timer in my application so that I can send a Heartbeat even if the Screen is locked (I need to do this in a short interval, let's assume every minute). But it seems that I have no WiFi connection when the screen is locked.

```
_timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 30000);

private async void TimerCallback(object state)
{
    try
    {
        await MobileApiService.Heartbeat();
    }
    catch(Exception e) { }
}
```

This code keeps executing (until the app is suspended but that is OK) but it throws the following Exception when the phone is locked:

> The text associated with this error code could not be found.
>
> A connection with the server could not be established

Is there anything I can do? Something like SomeWifiManager::RequestConnection()?

Comment: Remember that when you run app in Relese mode - your timer won't work - when app is suspended, all perocesses are cancelled (apart from ExtendedExecution case) - take a look at [app's lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle). Have you thought about BackgroundTasks?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i edited the text. It is ok that it stopps executing when the app is suspended, I handle this case allready. The problem with a BackgroundTask is that the 15 minute Intervall is too long. I need to know if the app is running (if not i will release some locks on the server-side). This MUST happen in a shorter intervall than 15 minutes.

Comment: AFAIK the app will be suspended shortly when the screen is locked. Have you tried with extended execution if you need to run for the app little longer? How long does it have to run when screen is locked?

Comment: It would be nice if I would be able to send a Heartbeat every 1-2 minutes until the user closes the app. But I'm giving up on this. No easy way to do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevet screen locking:

```
var dr = new Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest(); 

try {
    dr.RequestActive(); 
} catch {
}

try {
    dr.RequestRelease(); 
} catch {
}
```

When the screen is on, Wi-Fi also keeps on. It also prevents app suspension due to user inactivity.

More details on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.display.displayrequest.aspx?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP5000527).

Comment: Thank you, but I need a way to turn off the screen and keep the app running (to save power) in a shorter periodic intervall than 15 minutes. But this seems not to be possible.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can fill entire app screen with black rectangle, but I think it will save power only on devices with ClearBlack display.